# Calculate curvature of wave

Tags: curvature

I am looking for a way to calculate curvature of this wave (pic attached) in matlab.

[Sinc Wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywcpg.png)

I have generated this wave form in Matlab.

```
 t2 = linspace(6,2);
y2 = sinc(t2);
subplot(212),plot(t2,y2);
xlabel('Time (sec)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Sinc Function: 04');
```

Would be grateful if some one can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the curvature of a line that is defined by a *graph* $\{(x,f(x)\}$ of a function $f:D\subset \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ you can easily do that by following formula:

$$k(x) = \frac{f''(x)}{(1+(f'(x))^2)^{3/2}}$$

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph)